# Const_cast on a this pointer - would I get told off by other C++ coders for doing this?

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class `Game` e.g.

```
class Game
{
    public:
        InitObjects();
        ...
};
```

And I have another class `Grid`, that needs to be initialised with a non-const reference to that `Game` object. ( A `Grid` object needs to call functions that can update a `Game` object ).

```
class Grid
{
    public:
        Grid(Game & g):
            game(g){}
        ...
    private:
        Game & game;
        ...
};
```

The `Game` object is responsible for initialising the `Grid`. I did this:

```
void Game::InitObjects()
{
    grid = new Grid(*(const_cast<Game*>(this)) );
}
```

`grid` is not a member of a `Game` - it's a global ( argh - i know... I don't mind making it a member, but I have the same problem right? ).
Can some seasoned C++ folk tell me if this odd looking `const_cast` is acceptable?

Comment: What? `InitObjects` isn't `const` so the `const_cast` is pointless. I would say "not acceptable" but I think we need more context.

Comment: Is InitObjects declared as const? If not, why do you think the const_cast is necessary?

Comment: Ah. Hmm. When I did `grid = new Grid(*this)` I saw a warning about `this` being const. However, I just did it again, and no warning. Sorry everyone. I thought that the `this` pointer was always `const` or something.

Comment: @everyone - fine by me if you want to vote to close this... i did!

Comment: I don't think a close is necessary.  Whilst your `const_cast` looks unnecessary and there may well not be a problem, the fact that you have come to the conclusion there is no issue is an answer in of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen more horrible things in my time without casting at all.

```
class A
{
private:
   A * non_const_this;

public:

   A() : non_const_this( this )
   {
   }

   void changesme(); // non-const

   void method() const
   {
      non_const_this->changesme();
   }
};
```

The above code I have given is "I am in a non-const function now so I will grab a non-const reference to myself so I can change the object later when I need to even when I am in a const context". Which is actually worse than your possible scenario (if createObjects() is const) that is saying "This function is const because it is not changing the state now, but needs to pass out a non-const reference to self as my state will change later".

Of course better than the const modifier in the first place would be a split interface (mutable interface to an object derives from non-mutable one).

What I am looking at above is the one-to-one relationship between Game and Grid. Grid has a reference to one Game and Game's initObjects knows of one Grid. So the two are very tightly coupled. That does not necesasrily mean they should be one object - again split interface - you might want to pass a Grid& or a Game& reference for use of the interface of that class only.

Is InitObjects called from the constructor?

Comment: thank you - your answer is really interesting. Yes Game and Grid are in a one-to-one relationshiop. Do you mean pass a `Grid&` to `Game` functions? Yes `InitObjects()` is indeed called from the constructor.

Comment: I refer to a split interface whereby you effectively have one object but two different interfaces to it that you can pass about. You could actually derive a class from both Grid and Game and pass your object as a reference to whichever interface you ere exposing. Instead of inheriting from both classes you can also use composition to achieve this (or aggregation which is very similar, the difference is usually a lifetime one), which seems to be close to what you are doing here. init() functions should be private and normally exist only where you have multiple constructors that want to call it.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with const_cast is that it violates a promise of not causing any change to the object.  It is mainly needed for interfacing with modules (C-modules?) where const isn't used consistently and you are supposed to verify whether there could be any change.
An alternative might be to have some mutable members, but of course, these should be mutable by design (like locks, caches), not by convenience (hey, I want to change this when the object issupposed to be const).

The problem with your question is that nothing is const in your question, so I don't see any need for const_cast.

Answer (score 1):

Given `InitObjects` is not `const`, unless you are calling `InitObjects` on a `const Game` instance, there is no need for the `const_cast`. I'd be vary of that circular dependency though

Answer (score 0):

Construction from an object should not write to the object, so you won't be invoking UB (which you would be by writing to something that you de-consted through `const_cast`). However, this does look odd. Especially since `Game::InitObjects()` is not a `const` member function. Why do you think that the `this` pointer is `const`?!